# TYPO3 - Custom extension : show in flexform

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-extensions

I made my own extension on TYPO3 6.2 with the Extension Builder, the goal is to let the backend users create events (with name, location, date, number of people etc...) of our company.

- I created a backend plugin, it works good.
- I created a frontend plugin, but **I don't know how to write my flexform file** in order to let the backend users choose which event to display (through the "show" action I guess)... Best result would be to get a select list with all existing events.

How to do it ?

In my ext_localconf.php, I have :

```
<?php

    \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
        'Mycompany.' . $_EXTKEY,
        'Displayevent',
        array(
            'Event' => 'show',
            
        ),
        // non-cacheable actions
        array(
            'Event' => 'show',
            
        )
    );
    
?>
```

but in frontend there is a Typo3 error :

> ## 1298012500: Required argument "event" is not set for Mycompany\MycompanyEvents\Controller\EventController->show

here my showAction() code :

```
/**
 * action show
 *
 * @param \MyCompany\mycompany_events\Domain\Model\Event $event
 * @return void
 */
public function showAction(\MyCompany\mycompany_events\Domain\Model\Event $event) {
    $this->view->assign('event', $event);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to follow below steps to call flexform.

in your `ext_tables.php` file add below code.

```
//extenstion name
$extensionName = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::underscoredToUpperCamelCase($_EXTKEY);

//plugin integration
$frontendpluginName = 'your_plugin_name';
$pluginSignature = strtolower($extensionName) . '_'.strtolower(
    $frontendpluginName
);

$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['list']['subtypes_addlist'][$pluginSignature] = 'pi_flexform';
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPiFlexFormValue(
    $pluginSignature,
    'FILE:EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/Configuration/FlexForms/configure_plugin.xml'
);
```

Now, create flexform file in this directory `/Configuration/FlexForms/` like below and use userFunct for event select list.

```
<T3DataStructure>
    <sheets>
        <!--
            ################################
              SHEET General Settings
            ################################
        -->
        <sDEF>
            <ROOT>
                <TCEforms>
                    <sheetTitle>General</sheetTitle>
                </TCEforms>
                <type>array</type>
                <el>
                    <settings.variable_name>
                      <TCEforms>
                        <label>Title</label>
                        <config>
                            <type>select</type>
                            <itemsProcFunc>EXT:ext_key/Classes/Utility/class.tx_event_utility.php:tx_event_utility->getEventList</itemsProcFunc>
                            <multiple>0</multiple>
                            <minitems>0</minitems>
                            <maxitems>50</maxitems>
                            <size>5</size>
                        </config>
                      </TCEforms>
                    </settings.variable_name>
                </el>               
            </ROOT>
        </sDEF>
    </sheets>
</T3DataStructure>
```

Now, Create `tx_event_utility.php` file on this path `/ext_key/Classes/Utility/` like below.

```
<?php
class tx_event_utility {

    protected $objectManager;
    protected $configurationManager;
    protected $pluginSetting;
    protected $objectCategoryRepository;

    function __construct() {
        $this->objectManager = TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager');
        $this->configurationManager = $this->objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Configuration\\ConfigurationManager');
        $this->pluginSetting = $this->configurationManager->getConfiguration(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Configuration\ConfigurationManagerInterface::CONFIGURATION_TYPE_FULL_TYPOSCRIPT);
        $this->objectCategoryRepository = $this->objectManager->get('added repositry namespace');
   }

   function getEventList($config, $item) {

            // write code for geting event list
        }
        return $config;
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks ! Now the backend users get a list in flexform with all the events. But the error is still here (Typo3 doesn't understand it has to use the value from flexform?)

Comment: The same as at the beginning -> Required argument "event" is not set for Mycompany\MycompanyEvents\Controller\EventController->show

Comment: Please update your showAction() code in controller.php file. So i can check and provide suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for your help ; it's done. I don't understand how TYPO3 could know that the $event to display in the showAction() is the one from the plugin... By the way, my controller and twig views were generated by the Extension Builder ;)

Comment: No, I still have the error. What is done is to let users choose in the backend the event to show, but in frontend it doesn't display

Comment: I had the same problem and for me the solution was to simply remove the $event variable from the showAction Function. So `public function showAction(Event $event)` became `public function showAction()`.
And in the showAction you can just get the uid with `$this->settings["variable_name"]` and by using a repository function then the whole model. My showAction function:
    `public function showAction() { $event = $this->eventRepository->getEventByID($this->settings["event"])->getFirst(); $this->view->assign('event', $event); }`

Answer (score 0):

Add file Yourext/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php

```
<?php
defined('TYPO3_MODE') or die();

// register plugin and flexform
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
        'yourext',
        'Name',
        'LLL:EXT: yourext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_be.xlf:name_plugin'
);
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['list']['subtypes_excludelist']['yourext_name'] = 'select_key';
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['list']['subtypes_addlist']['yourext_name'] = 'pi_flexform';
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPiFlexFormValue(
        'yourext_name',
        'FILE:EXT:yourext/Configuration/FlexForms/flexform.xml'
);
```